# Convert Json object to entity

Tags: c#, json

I would like to see some of your suggestions on how to build entities in C# to fit this Json

```
{  
"activities-heart": [
    {
      "dateTime": "2016-10-25",
      "value": {
        "customHeartRateZones": [],
        "heartRateZones": [
          {
            "max": 88,
            "min": 30,
            "name": "Out of Range"
          },
          {
            "max": 123,
            "min": 88,
            "name": "Fat Burn"
          },
          {
            "max": 150,
            "min": 123,
            "name": "Cardio"
          },
          {
            "max": 220,
            "min": 150,
            "name": "Peak"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "activities-heart-intraday": {
    "dataset": [],
    "datasetInterval": 1,
    "datasetType": "minute"
  }
}
```

[This Site](http://json2csharp.com/#) suggested:

```
public class HeartRateZone
{
    public int max { get; set; }
    public int min { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public List<object> customHeartRateZones { get; set; }
    public List<HeartRateZone> heartRateZones { get; set; }
}

public class ActivitiesHeart
{
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
}

public class ActivitiesHeartIntraday
{
    public List<object> dataset { get; set; }
    public int datasetInterval { get; set; }
    public string datasetType { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ActivitiesHeart> __invalid_name__activities-heart { get; set; }
    public ActivitiesHeartIntraday __invalid_name__activities-heart-intraday { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that this returns nothing, it tries to build the entities but they are null. Is there something that the converter and i don't see.

Comment: try NewtonSoft Json dll

Comment: Can you show the deserialize code?

Comment: *"My problem is that this returns nothing, it tries to build the entities but they are null."* returns nothing when? Where's your code to deserialize the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `NewtonSoft` to deserialize the json (and pretty sure that the following is also correct to other deserializers) the problem is with your classes.

If for your classes I run the following line, as you described I get `null` values in the properties.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Now if you look at the classes you have **they don't even compile**:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<ActivitiesHeart> __invalid_name__activities-heart { get; set; }
    public ActivitiesHeartIntraday __invalid_name__activities-heart-intraday { get; set; }
}
```

And the website even told you that ***the property names are invalid***: `__invalid_name__activities-heart`. You can't have property names with `-` in them..

**To fix it you need to:**

1. Change the property names in the classes to valid names + update json with new names:

   ```
   public class RootObject
   {
       public List<ActivitiesHeart> ActivitiesHeart { get; set; }
       public ActivitiesHeartIntraday ActivitiesHeartIntraday { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Or better, change property names and then as Jim suggested use the `JsonPropertyAttribute`:

   ```
   public class RootObject
   {
       [JsonProperty("activities-heart")]
       public List<ActivitiesHeart> ActivitiesHeart { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("activities-heart-intraday")]
       public ActivitiesHeartIntraday ActivitiesHeartIntraday { get; set; }
   }
   ```

it will work

Comment: How about `[JsonProperty("activities-heart")]` and `[JsonProperty("activities-heart-intraday")]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thnx with the JsonProperty it worked right away.

Belowis the way Icall the api and deserialize, just if anyone else need the help.

```
var apiCall = ToFullUrl("/1/user/{0}/activities/heart/date/{1}/{2}.json", encodedUserId, ToFitbitFormat(startDate), ToFitbitFormat(endDateOrPeriod));
HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(apiCall);
await HandleResponse(response);string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
RootObject entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBody);
```